# How to bind items in a wx.Choice component to functions?

Tags: python, wxpython, dropdownchoice

I am trying to use wx.Choice component to archieve a simple application.

The idea is, a number of items are listed in the wx.Choice, and each of them will trigger an unique function.

My first version of code was:

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, 0, 'wxPython pull-down choice', size = (400, 300))
        panel_select_model= wx.Panel(self, -1)
        model_list = ['Test_A', 'Test_B']
        self._model_type = None

        self._stat_tex = wx.StaticText(panel_select_model, 1, "Select Model Type:", (15, 20))
        self._droplist = wx.Choice(panel_select_model, 2, (150, 18), choices = model_list)

        """ Bind A Panel """
        self._droplist.SetSelection(0)
        self._droplist.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.Test_A_click)
```

But it turns out that the two items in the dropdown list will trigger the same function (I expect that the `Test_A` will trigger that function and `Test_B` simply do nothing). So I try to bind `Test_B` to another method `Test_B_click`

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, 0, 'wxPython pull-down choice', size = (400, 300))
        panel_select_model= wx.Panel(self, -1)
        model_list = ['Test_A', 'Test_B']
        self._model_type = None

        self._stat_tex = wx.StaticText(panel_select_model, 1, "Select Model Type:", (15, 20))
        self._droplist = wx.Choice(panel_select_model, 2, (150, 18), choices = model_list)

        """ Bind A Panel """
        self._droplist.SetSelection(0)
        self._droplist.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.Test_A_click)

        """ Bind B Panel """
        self._droplist.SetSelection(1)
        self._droplist.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.Test_B_click)
```

The above code display a main frame, a drop list in it and two items in the drop list. However, when I click either of the two items, no function is triggered anymore.

So, how can I archieve my goal: **Bind different functions to each of the items in a wx.Choice component, and make them trigger functions correctly.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am coming back to ask my own question. I don't think this is the perfect solution, but it managed my way out.

Here is the code:

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

```
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, 0, 'wxPython pull-down choice', size = (400, 300))
    panel_select_model= wx.Panel(self, -1)
    model_list = ['Test_A', 'Test_B']
    self._model_type = None

    self._stat_tex = wx.StaticText(panel_select_model, 1, "Select Model Type:", (15, 20))
    self._droplist = wx.Choice(panel_select_model, 2, (150, 18), choices = model_list)

    """ Bind A Panel """
    self._droplist.SetSelection(0)
    self._droplist.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.choice_click)

    """ Bind B Panel """
    self._droplist.SetSelection(1)
    self._droplist.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.choice_click)

def choice_click(self, event):
    if self._droplist.GetStringSelection() == "Test_A":
        self.Test_A__click()
    elif self._droplist.GetStringSelection() == "Test_B":
        self.Test_B_click()
```

In above code. I put another layer between the wx.Choice component and the functions that I would like to trigger. Once we have a match, its corresponding function will be triggered.

I am afraid this is not an effective way. So I would be extremely appreciate if anyone can bring up a good solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think using a central callback function for the whole dropdown menu, which delegates to a secondary callback function based on the item selected, is probably the best way to go. To make it cleaner, you could store the item-specific callback functions in a dictionary, keyed by the respective item text; that would avoid the long `if`-`elif` chain in your `choice_click` method.

Answer (score 2):

Your methodology is probably the most common way to do what you want and it's pretty easy to tell what's going on as well. However if you do this with a little dash of meta-programming that might be a little cleaner if you set it up correctly:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Callbacks")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.choice = wx.Choice(panel, choices=["test_A", "test_B"])
        self.choice.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.onChoice)
        self.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onChoice(self, event):
        choice = self.choice.GetStringSelection()
        method = getattr(self, "on_%s" % choice)
        method()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_test_A(self):
        print "You chose test_A!"

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_test_B(self):
        print "You chose test_B!"


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Here we use Python's **getattr** function to determine which method to actually call. This allows us to skip the use of the **if** statement, but assumes that we have all the methods set up for all the choices in the control.